# Why does site shows A page can have only one server-side Form tag

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I am creating a modal in an aspx form which will add data in database. But it is showing this error

> A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

I did the same in another file on same project where I created a Login page which worked completely fine. It also had 2 forms, the default one and the one I created. But here it is showing error although I have tried removing `runat="server"` from the second form but still no solution.

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsiblenavbar">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.aspx">
                    <img src="logo.ico" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.aspx"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp; home &nbsp;</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="logout.aspx"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>&nbsp; logout &nbsp;</a>
                    </li>
                    <%--<asp:listview runat="server" id="listview1" --%>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <p></p>
        <style>
            p {
                line-height: 5px;
            }
        </style>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="user.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">profile info</h5>
                            <%--<p class="card-text" id="para1"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>&nbsp;taimoor baig</p>--%>
                            <asp:Label ID="label1" CssClass="card-text fa fa-user-circle-o" runat="server">&nbsp;</asp:Label>
                            <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>&nbsp;admin</p>
                            <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;last login : xx-xx-xxxx</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-edit">&nbsp;edit profile</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="jumbotron" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <h1>welcome admin</h1>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i6ovwi4o/n106/szw160/szh160/hoc222/hbw6/cf100/hgr0/hcw2/hcd88/fan2/fas20/fdi70/mqc000/mqs3/mql13/mqw6/mqd94/mhc000/mhs3/mhl13/mhw6/mhd94/mmc000/mml5/mmw1/mmd94/hwm2/hhs2/hhl55/hhb18/hhw8/hms2/hml85/hmb18/hmw8/hmr7/hss3/hsl90/hsr5" frameborder="0" width="160" height="160"></iframe>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="card" <%--style="font-size: large;"--%>>
                                    <div class="card-body" style="width: 20rem;">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">new orders</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">here you can add new orders.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">new orders</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">brand</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">here you can manage brand.</p>
                            <a href="brand.aspx" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form_brand" class="btn btn-primary">add brand</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success fa fa-edit" style="height: 36px;">&nbsp;manage brand</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">product</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">here you can manage products.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">add product</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success fa fa-edit" style="height: 36px;">&nbsp;manage products</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">market</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">here you can manage markets.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">add market</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success fa fa-edit" style="height: 36px;">&nbsp;manage markets</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">salesman</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">here you can manage salesman.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">add salesman</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success fa fa-edit" style="height: 40px; width: 9rem">&nbsp;manage salesman</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">vendor</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">here you can manage vendor.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">add vendor</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success fa fa-edit" style="height: 36px;">&nbsp;manage vendors</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- modal of brand -->
<div class="modal fade" id="form_brand" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="examplemodallabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">add new brand</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div runat="server" class="modal-body">
                <form runat="server">
                    <div class="form-group" runat="server">
                        <label>brand name</label>
                        <%--<input type="text" class="form-control" name="brand_name" id="brand_name" placeholder="enter brand name"/>--%>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="textbox1" runat="server">
                            enter brand name
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>brand sector name</label>
                        <%--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="brand_sector_name" placeholder="enter brand sector name"/>--%>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                            enter brand sector name
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        <small id="brand_sector__error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>vendor dealing</label>
                        <%--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="vendor_dealing" placeholder="enter vendor name"/>--%>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="textbox3" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                            enter vendor name
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        <small id="vendor_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                    </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect a webform with a modal displaying after pressing the "add brand" button

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two form tag, 1 in master page and 1 in the page that throws the error.

Try to remove 1

Comment: I can't I used bootstrap modal in which has a form of it's own